# grails gsp javascript integration, how to escape variables?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a gsp page (template) where I need to include some javascript. In the example below, how would I get the remoteFunction to understand, the moneyTransId will be set by the javascript function?  MoneyTransId comes out fine in the alert, but I can't get it to work in the remoteFunction, and apparently need to escape it somehow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmVoid(moneyTransId) {
   var r = confirm("Please confirm the void");
   if (r == true) {
        alert("ID is: " +moneyTransId);
        ${remoteFunction(action:"voidTransaction", id:moneyTransId)};
          ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
${remoteFunction(action:'voidTransaction', params:'\'id=\'+moneyTransId')};
```

This way, you won't mix server-side code with client-side code.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Server side variables and statements can not read client side (javascript) variables. 
Server side code runs first, then html and javascript get generated and sent to the client (browser). Then the browser renders HTML and runs javascript. Hope this helps your thought process.
Dmitry.

Comment: Thanks DmitryB. Please note, I just want the remoteFunction to leave moneyTransId alone, just like moneyTransId is left alone in the alert.  That way, when the confirmVoid function runs, the value for moneyTransId can be set inside whatever remoteFunction expands to.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand but you can't set moneyTransitId in the remoteFunction from the javascript ID. It has to be a string literal: try 'moneyTransId'

Comment: Yah, I did, and a few other variations I could think of.  No dice.  Why can't it let the variable "pass through" to the javascript function?